# Is there any Automated unit test generator for Map-Reduce?

Tags: java, junit, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently using MRUnit for writing unit tests for Map-Reduce. So my question is: 
Is there any tool which automatically generates unit-test for map-reduce?